# AS400 Java set library for file at runtime

Tags: java, sql, ibm-midrange

I have written a Java program that is executed on an iSeries AS400. Within that program, I use a JDBC connection to the same machine to query data from the files like

```
select *
from xyzcapad.myFile
where lastName = 'Max'
```

The same file name and structure (not data!) exist in multiple libraries because we have multiple environments on our AS400 and each has its own default libraries.

So when I now start the program and run it in the environment that is using library xyzcapad, all works well. But if I run it in another env., how can I tell my program to use the other default library for that table?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using JDBC, you can use the `SET SCHEMA` statement to select a library like this:

```
set schema xyzcapad;
```

Then execute your sql like this:

```
select *
  from myFile
  where lastName = 'Max';
```

Notice the table name is not qualified. In that case it will use the default schema which was set using the `set schema` statement above.

EDIT

Here my final code that got it working:

```
    public void connectAS400(){
        as400 = new AS400("my.company.com","user","password");
        AS400JDBCDataSource datasource = new AS400JDBCDataSource(as400);

//      datasource.setLibraries("xyzcapad");
        datasource.setTranslateBinary(true);
        datasource.setNaming("system");
        try {
            connection = datasource.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but actually I needed something to retrieve the information in what environment I am currently in the first place. I figured that when using the AS400 objects and it's datasource, the API takes care of that automatically :)

Comment: I was going to suggest `system` naming which defaults to using the library list, but then I saw your edit and accepted that.